# Counting number of events from CSV file that occurred in corresponding polygon feature class using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, csv, statistics

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of drought events per county over the last 70 years we've had in NC and am having some difficulty. I downloaded a CSV file from a NOAA website that includes each drought event with a unique EVENT_ID field and (with some finagling) a county name field. I have a feature class of the counties in NC and would like to be able to create a new feature class that has a count field that shows how many events occurred in each county.

It seems fairly straightforward but I can't seem to figure out how to make it happen. I've tried using a join and exporting the results, but like I said, I just can't seem to get it to produce the value I need.

Any suggestions?

I'm using ArcMap 10.5 and the CSV file doesn't contain any "spatial" info (i.e., no lat/long), only includes the county name where the event occurred.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Have you tried Summary Statistics on your csv, then join the results to the feature class? Then you need to export it to a new feature class to save the results.